# Access data-attributes with .closest().attr() in Bootstrap Confirmation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-fleet-id="438935" class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 list-wrap">
    <a data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="top" class="list-item-link-1" title="" data-original-title="Delete List">
        <span class="label label-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I include both Bootstrap and Bootstrap Confirmation scripts and then add the following code to enable Bootstrap Confirmation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-item-link-1').confirmation({
        onConfirm: function () {
            var list_id = $(this).closest(".list-wrap").attr("data-fleet-id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "server/delete_list.php",
                data: {
                    'list_id': list_id
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {},
                error: function () {
                    alert("AJAX error.");
                }
            });
        },
        btnOkLabel: '<i class="icon-ok-sign icon-white"></i>',
        btnCancelLabel: '<i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>'
    });
});
```

The problem is that I cannot access the `data-fleet-id` of the `.list-wrap` class. The var value is in fact `undefined`.

This is the `console.log($(this))` result:

[image]

Comment: just use `parent()` as `var list_id = $(this).parent().attr("data-fleet-id");`

Comment: try using this.parent()

Comment: If you `console.log(this)` what do you get? It would appear that `this` is not the element you're expecting it to be.

Comment: edited the post with the console.log.

Comment: how about `console.log($(this)[0])`?

Comment: why dont you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net